# Convergence in Distribution of a random function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $H$ be a hilbert space and suppose that we have a sequence of random elements $\chi_n\in H$, $\chi_0\in H$. Let $\{\phi_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an complete orthonormal basis in $H$. Suppose that I know that $\int \chi_n \phi_j \xrightarrow{D} \int \chi_0\phi_j$ for each fixed $j$.

**Question:** Does this tell me that $\chi_n$ converges weakly to $\chi_0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Counterexample**

I am still not sure what you mean by $\xrightarrow{D}$ but if I interpret it as a limit in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ then I have an adequate counterexample now.

Notation: $(f,g) = \int f \cdot\bar{g} \,\mathrm{d}\lambda$ (the Hilbertspace scalarproduct)

Assumption: There is a sequence $\chi_n$ in $H$ and a vector $\chi_0 \in H$ such that $$\lim_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\chi_n - \chi_0,\phi_i)=0\quad\text{for each fixed}\quad j \in \mathbb{N}$$
Where $\phi_i$ is an ONB of $H$.

Now choose $\chi_n = n\cdot \phi_n$, $\;\chi_0 = 0$ and $g = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}\phi_j$. Then the condtion
$$(\chi_n,\phi_i) \to (\chi_0,\phi_i)$$
is satisfied. Clearly $(\chi_0,g) = 0$ but

$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\chi_n,g) = \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}(n\phi_n,\phi_i) = \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}n (\phi_n,\phi_n) = 1 \neq 0 = (\chi_0,g)$$

So there is a $g \in H$ such that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\chi_n,g) \neq (\chi_0,g)$ which contradicts the weak convergence.

**Old Post:**

As I finished my counterexample I noticed that I ignored that there is an element $\chi_0 \in H$. In my counterexample there can't be such a $\chi_0$. But maybe you can see what this $\chi_0$ must give you.

**Counterexample**

Choose $\chi_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j$ and $g = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}\phi_j$. then you know $(\chi_n,\phi_j) \to 1$ but $$(\chi_n,g) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} $$
which will not converge. So $\chi_n$ doesn't converge weakly.

Comment: I think this is not a good counterexample, since I assume that $(\chi_n,\phi_j) = 1 \xrightarrow{D} (g,\phi_j) = 1/j$. This is not true to begin with in your example. NB: if $\chi_n$ converges weakly to $\chi_0$ then this means that for all bounded continuous functions $f$, $\int fdP_n \rightarrow \int fdP_0$, where $P_n$ and $P_0$ are the probability measures associated to $\chi_n$ and $\chi_0$ respectively.

Comment: Okay maybe i got something wrong but what do you mean by $\xrightarrow{D}$ because $\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\chi_n,\phi_j) \neq (g,\phi_j)$.

Comment: okay now I understand the mixup weakly convergence in context of functional analysis means convergence for every element of the topological dualspace

Comment: I updated my counterexample!

Comment: $\chi_n$ is a random function, so $(\chi_n,\phi_j)$ is a random variable. So when I say $\xrightarrow{D}$ I mean convergence in distribution. Sorry for not clarifying that earlier!

Comment: So since both $\chi_n$ and $\chi_0$ don't have to lie on the same probability space, they may have the same distribution in the conventional sense of random variables, their probability measures match up on a particular space, and in this case that would be $H$, with Borel Algebra say, $S$. I think there is something here, but I'm wondering if this could be rephramed in terms of probability measures, because this doesn't necessarily *port* straight into random functions

Comment: Addendum: since $(\chi_n,\phi_j)$ and $(\chi_0,\phi_j)$ are random variables, $lim_n (\chi_n-\chi_0,\phi_j)= 0$ may not necessarily be true especially if $\chi_n$ and $\chi_0$ lie on separate probability spaces, but it can still hold true that $(\chi_n,\phi_j) \xrightarrow{d} (\chi_0,\phi_j)$.

Comment: In terms of convergence in distribution, $(\chi_n,g) =1$ almost surely, which means that $0$ is not a continuity point of distribution function, nor is it a continuity point of $(\chi_0,g)=0$, since all its mass is concentrated at 0. Hence, it may still possibly converge in distribution, but not pointwise.

Comment: Okay so $\chi_n$ and $\chi_0$ are not elements from $H$ but $\chi_n: \Omega_n \to H$. Maybe you should mention that in your question. For clarification add the measures and the sets in your integrals.